# Can't locate CPAN.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5

Tags: linux, perl, fedora-core

I tried to install some modules to a new server (fedora core 18) but I'm getting this error:

```
Can't locate CPAN.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

The module I need to install is : XML/Writer.pm

because I'm getting this error:

```
Can't locate XML/Writer.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .
```

Do any of you know why, or how can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Some OS distributions cut out pieces of the core Perl distributions. In this case, it appears that the very tool to install modules was gutted out, so you need to get the OS to install it.

Try to install CPAN using

```
yum -y install perl-CPAN
```

and then use `cpan` command to install the required modules

```
cpan XML::Writer
```

Comment: Fedora is famous for chopping core `perl` into many different RPMs. That's why I like to always use perlbrew.